# Android studio, adding button to spinner layout stops the spinner from working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have a problem where before i added the button to the spinner, the spinner was working fine. As soon as i put the button into the spinners layout it stops the spinner from working but the button works fine. What i mean by the spinner stops working i mean it stops recognising clicks.

Heres the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

     <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:clickable="false"
        />
     <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right" android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
     <ImageButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/playbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```